# Check and convert scientific values less than 1E-6 to 0

Tags: regex, perl

I have pipe delimited data coming from upstream source, something like this

```
|8.885462831458033E-14|null                |5.695499664518404E-14|4.296341514201562E-5|null    |5.276825671459783E-13|null                    
|-8.454061592042423E-16  |null                    |null             |null             |null             |1.0431823334324647E-12    
|1.9126743167833942|-6.263817465600774E-13                      |-1.6982217957458542E-12                    |-9.225453795675166E-13                      
|6.523123024471167E-14            |-8.536267683965616E-13                  |1.1356936506492975E-12        |1.4853780464293662E-12           
|null                    |null                   |null                   |null                      |null                 |null                    
|9.60387559316213E-16         |null                               |null                             |null                            |null                          
|null                        |null                         |null                            |null                             |null                            
|null                                   |null            |null                     |null                     |null                  |null                         
|null                                 |null                               |null                    |null                        |null                              
|null                           |null                           |null                              |null                      |null                      
|null                 |null                   |null            |null                 |-6.5338923092015155E-15       |3.755430461321554E-15            
|-3.777155566881811E-15            |null                   |null             |null         |null                                   |null                                   
|null                     |null             |null               |null                 |null         |6.504507931797634E-16         |null                          
|0.02614132715745261|7.040850390545314E-15 |4.948049601667298E-15 |-1.1154821252871935E-12|null           |2.5365347638363504E-13
|8.570467385590559E-14|null                 |null                |null                 |null                   |-4.2301863953793406E-16
|null                   |null                  |null                  |null        |null             |null             |null
```

And I want to replace the values that are less than 1E-6 to 0.
To give an example

The first line

```
|8.885462831458033E-14|null |5.695499664518404E-14|4.296341514201562E-5|null |5.276825671459783E-13|null
```

should be

```
|0|null |0|4.296341514201562E-5|null |0|null
```

I'm trying Perl

```
perl - pe ' s/([0-9.])+E(\+|\-)(\d)+/0/g ' file
```

but it is not giving correct results and not working for all scenarios

Answer (score 2):

```bash
perl -Mv5.14 -pe's/[^|]*E([^|]+)/ $1 < -6 ? 0 : $& /eg'
```

More strict:

```bash
perl -Mv5.14 -F'\|' -lane'
   s/^[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?E([-+]\d+)\z/ $1 < -6 ? 0 : $& /ae for @F;
   say join "|", @F;
'
```

Neither handles `-Inf` or values like `0.00000000001`.

Comment: Great.. it works. Can you add explanation for the second one.. what does ````/a```` do here?

Comment: Makes `\d` equivalent to `[0-9]`. It normally matches 370 difference code points.

Answer (score 2):

One way that avoids regular expressions, instead using [`Scalar::Util::looks_like_number`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util#looks_like_number) to work out if a field is numberish enough to compare to 1e-6:

```bash
$ perl -MScalar::Util=looks_like_number -F'\|' -lane 'print join("|", map { looks_like_number($_) && $_ < 1e-6 ? 0 : $_ } @F)' input.txt
|0|null                |0|4.296341514201562E-5|null    |0|null
etc.
```

Comment: this also works.. is this fool proof?. since the funciton says "like" and may fail in some cases?.

Comment: As long as your numbers exactly follow Perl's definition of what string it considers a number, yes. Note that `Scalar::Util::looks_like_number('-Inf')` is false, so this does not cover `-Inf` either. It does consider `0 but true`, `00`, `+0` numbers. And leading and trailing spaces are ignored, I think